# Store image file as blob in database using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I am using google cloud SQL as database....I am fetching image content via UrlFetch and then converting FetchResponse to blob....But when I am trying to get blob data from database and trying to upload that as image it is not working....

```
Code : 
 var base = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'; 
 var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('contacts', base);
 fetchArgs.method='GET'
 var photoURL==// url for image
 var image=UrlFetchApp.fetch(photoURL,fetchArgs)
 var imageBlob=image.getBlob()
```

imageBlob will be stored in database where PHOTO field has type of LONgBLOB in database

now i am trying to fetch photo

```
 var conn  = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://"+instance_name+"/"+database_name);
  var stmt=conn.createStatement()
  var query="select PHOTO from user_info"
  var rs=stmt.executeQuery(query)
  rs.next()
  var image=rs.getBlob(1)
```

Now using this blob into html file as:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
    <p>This is image</p>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Base64.encode(image) width="100" height="100"/ >
      <p> This is image</p>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is not displaying any image it just dislpys image area....Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong..

Actual code :
Web script :

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("image").evaluate();

}

function myFunction(){
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://"+instance_name+"/"+database_name);
  var stmt=conn.createStatement()
  var query="select PHOTO from user_info"
  var rs=stmt.executeQuery(query)
  rs.next()
  var image=rs.getBlob(1)
  stmt.close()
  conn.close()
  return image
}
```

image.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
    <p>This is image</p>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Base64.encode(<?= myFunction()?>) width="100" height="100"/ >
      <p> This is image</p>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML file has some inconsistent quoting, are you using that as a [template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#PullingData)? Also, the correct base64 encode function is [base64Encode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#base64Encode). Perhaps that is also an issue?

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<!=Utilities.base64Encode(image)?>" width="100" height="100"/ >`

Ensure that you are passing in the image parameter to the template to evaluate.

Full version should look like -

```
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
    <p>This is image</p>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<!=Utilities.base64Encode(myFunction()?>)" width="100" height="100"/ >
      <p> This is image</p>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes I using html file as template...actually I am using web script which shows the output of html file...In html file , for image parameter I am calling script function which return blob data..... you Wrote Utilities.base64Encode(image) function in html file, but this function is available for Apps script only....Is it right ??

Comment: Are you using some other base64 library then? Even then the `"` seems in the wrong place. It should after the `?>`. I've updated my example to also include a full HTML example. Give that a try and let us know what you see.